# Is there any sql interpreter for objects?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, interpreter

Is there any interpreter that takes a string or even a custom object as input and execute it on my datasource?
I cannot use linq to object because query always changes and the report i'm working on, has about 6000 queries which i can reduce to 9 if i find some tool doing that for me.

Opensource is very applicable.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the expression evaluation functionality within the (open source) Spring.NET library:

http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/expressions.html

Comment: Fast is a subjective term I guess, but I have never found it to be a bottleneck in my application.